# How to add a bar graph in my main.py and in kv file?

Tags: python-3.x, graph, kivy, bar-chart, kivy-language

I want to add a bar graph that only shows on the progress screen. I am new to Kivy and Python. I am using matplotlib for the bar graph. I want to integrate the Bar.py code into my main.py code and progress.kv file. I am getting stuck on how to add it in my Progress.kv file.

Bar.py

## This is the code for the bar graph I want to show.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x = [2,4,6,8,10]
y = [6,7,8,2,4]

x2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
y2 = [7,8,2,4,2]

plt.bar(x,y, label='Bars1', color='blue')
plt.bar(x2,y2, label='Bars2', color='c') 

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck It out')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Main.py

## I want to add the bar graph code into the 'Progress screen" instead of passing.

```
from kivy.app import App 
#kivy.require("1.10.0")
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, 
SlideTransition 
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label 
from kivy.graphics import *
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout   
from kivy.config import Config 
from kivy.lang import Builder 
import numpy as np 
from math import sin 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import 
FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib
from kivy.garden.matplotlib import FigureCanvasKivyAgg

#Screens created in kv file. Declare all screens for app.    
class Login(Screen):
    pass    
class Connected(Screen):
    pass    
class Patient(Screen):
    pass
class Progress(Screen):
    pass  
class Goals(Screen):
    pass 
class Training(Screen):
    pass
class Range(Screen):
    pass
class Trial(Screen):
    pass
class Symmetry(Screen):
    pass
class Coordination(Screen):
    pass
class Help(Screen):
    pass
class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass 
class ScreenApp(App):
    def build(self):
        m = Manager(transition=SlideTransition()) 
        return m
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #sets pixels to pixels on Raspberry Pi tablet
    Config.set('graphics', 'fullscreen', '0')
    Config.set('graphics', 'width', '800')
    Config.set('graphics', 'height', '480')
    ScreenApp().run()
```

Progress.kv

## I have all the code for the progress screen in a kv file. I would like to add the design and details here but if not, then in the main.py.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

<Progress>:
canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgb: 1, 1, 1 
    Rectangle:
        pos: self.pos
        size: self.size
Button:
    text:'Patient Menu'
    font_size: 20
    bold: True
    size_hint: None, None
    size: 300, 50
    pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .1 }   
    color: 1, 1, 1, 1               
    on_press: root.manager.current = 'Patient'
```

Answer (score 0):

### kv file

1. Instantiate a *BoxLayout* widget as children of class rule, `<Progress>:`
2. Add `id: bar` to the *BoxLayout* widget so that we can reference it in Python code.
3. Hook up the *BoxLayout*'s `id` to an ObjectProperty, `bar: bar`

[Kv language » self.ids vs ObjectProperty](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code)

> **Note**
>
> Although the self.ids method is very concise, it is ***generally
>   regarded as ‘best practice’ to use the ObjectProperty. This creates a
>   direct reference, provides faster access and is more explicit.***

### Python code

1. Add import statement, `from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty`
2. Add `bar = ObjectProperty(None)` at class level of `Progress()`
3. Implement `on_pre_enter()` method into class `Progress()`

[Declaration of a Property](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/events.html#declaration-of-a-property)

> To declare properties, you must declare them at the class level. The
>   class will then do the work to instantiate the real attributes when
>   your object is created. These properties are not attributes: they are
>   mechanisms for creating events based on your attributes.

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

from kivy.garden.matplotlib.backend_kivyagg import FigureCanvasKivyAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [2,4,6,8,10]
y = [6,7,8,2,4]

x2 = [1,3,5,7,9]
y2 = [7,8,2,4,2]

plt.bar(x,y, label='Bars1', color='blue')
plt.bar(x2,y2, label='Bars2', color='c')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.title('Interesting Graph\nCheck It out')
plt.legend()


class Patient(Screen):
    pass


class Progress(Screen):
    bar = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_pre_enter(self, *args):
        self.bar.add_widget(FigureCanvasKivyAgg(plt.gcf()))


class Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass


class ProgressApp(App):
    title = "Kivy Garden Matplolib & plt"

    def build(self):
        return Manager()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ProgressApp().run()
```

### kv file - progress.kv

```
#:kivy 1.11.0
#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition

<Manager>:
    transition: SlideTransition()

    Patient:
        name: 'Patient'

    Progress:
        name: 'Progress'

<Patient>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'

        Label:
            text: 'Patient Screen'
            font_size: '30sp'

        Button:
            size_hint: 1, 0.1
            text: 'Goto Progress Screen'
            on_release:
                root.manager.current = 'Progress'

<Progress>:
    bar: bar

    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        id: bar

    Button:
        text:'Patient Menu'
        font_size: 20
        bold: True
        size_hint: None, None
        size: 300, 50
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .1 }
        color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'Patient'
```

## Output

[image: Img01 - Bar graph]

Comment: When I run the main.py, the graph pops up first. But when I click exit, the app shut downs because of an Attribute error. I want the app to open to the main screen, then when I click the button to enter the Progress Screen, I want the graph to show up.

Comment: I don't want the graph to pop up until I am in the progress scree.

Comment: In the example provided, the first screen displayed is Patient. When the button, "Goto Progress Screen" is clicked, then it display the graph.

Comment: Make sure that all your kv file names are in lower case.

Comment: My kv files are in lower cases. I just made them uppercase on here.

Comment: In your ***screen.kv***, insert `#:` infront of import statement, `import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition`. It should be `#:import SlideTransition kivy.uix.screenmanager.SlideTransition`

Answer (score 0):

Progress.kv file for bar graph

```
#:import MeshLinePlot kivy.garden.graph.MeshLinePlot
#:import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils
<Progress>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: [10,20,10,20]
        spacing: 20
    Graph:
            height:1000
            width:1000
            id: graph_test
            xlabel:'Algorithms'
            ylabel:'Accuracy'
            x_ticks_minor:5
            x_tics_major:25
            y_ticks_major:1
            y_grid_label:True
            x_grid_label:True
            padding:5
            x_grid:True
            y_grid:True
            xmin:-0
            xmax:3
            ymin:0
            ymax:100
            pos: 0, root.height
            size: root.width, root.height
```

Python code for progress

```
import itertools

from kivy.app import App

from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex as rgb

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, SlideTransition

from kivy.properties import StringProperty,ObjectProperty

from math import sin

from kivy.garden.graph import Graph, MeshLinePlot, BarPlot

colors = itertools.cycle([rgb('7dac9f'), rgb('dc7062'), rgb('66a8d4'), rgb('e5b060')])

class Progress(Screen):

    def assign(self):

        super(Progress,self).__init__()

        self.sensorEnabled = True
        self.graph= self.ids.graph_test

        self.plot = []
        self.plot.append(BarPlot(color=next(colors),bar_spacing=.72))  #x - Red
        self.plot.append(BarPlot(color=next(colors),bar_spacing=.72))  # Y - Green
        self.plot.append(BarPlot(color=next(colors),bar_spacing=.72))  # Z - Blue

        self.reset_plots(self.graph)

        for plot in self.plot:
            self.graph.add_plot(plot)

    def reset_plots(self,graph):
        for plot in self.plot:
            plot.bind_to_graph(graph)
            plot.points = []

        self.counter = 1
```